# Javascript JSON transform using Map, Reduce, Aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, react-native

I am beating my head trying to figure out this transformation.

This is the format of the JSON

### I have:

```
{
    "itineraryId": "063fc878-b118-49fc-9106-39d51f647c9e",
    "reservations": [
        {
            "confirmNumber": "54047SC008976",
            "startDate": "2021-11-20T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "confirmNumber": "54047SC008975",
            "startDate": "2021-11-13T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "confirmNumber": "54058SC007379",
            "startDate": "2021-08-13T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

### I need:

```
[{
    "itineraryId": "063fc878-b118-49fc-9106-39d51f647c9e",
    "month": "November 2021",
    "reservations": [{
            "confirmNumber": "54047SC008976",
            "startDate": "2021-11-20T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "confirmNumber": "54047SC008975",
            "startDate": "2021-11-13T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "itineraryId": "063fc878-b118-49fc-9106-39d51f647c9e",
    "month": "August 2021",
    "reservations": [{
        "confirmNumber": "54058SC007379",
        "startDate": "2021-08-13T00:00:00.000Z"
    }]
}]
```

I need it that way so that I can build a [SectionList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist) in my [react native app](https://snack.expo.dev/QESiPAt04). I tried so many different options (aggregate+map+reduce) but I m not able to get it to this format. Any guides I can follow to help me?

---

The problem is a lot more complicated but I have simplified it by removing all the unneeded data properties. I was able to figure out the structure I need by looking at the example in the SectionList page and figuring out the structure of that [image: Screenshot of JSON to TS]

Edit: Pasting the picture of what it looks like when I follow one of the solutions. Nov 2022 shows up before Nov 2021
[image]

Comment: @serlite Hey, I have updated the question with the screenshot of what it looks like

Answer (score 1):

I've often wished for some kind of easy "group by" function in JavaScript, but you can achieve the same effect with `reduce()`. Essentially, you can build up an array of grouped results by either creating or updating a group depending on if it already exists during each call to the reducer function:

```js
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

const initial = {
  "itineraryId": "063fc878-b118-49fc-9106-39d51f647c9e",
  "reservations": [{
      "confirmNumber": "54047SC008976",
      "startDate": "2021-11-20T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "confirmNumber": "54047SC008975",
      "startDate": "2021-11-13T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "confirmNumber": "54058SC007379",
      "startDate": "2021-08-13T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "confirmNumber": "54047SC008971",
      "startDate": "2020-11-13T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "confirmNumber": "54047SC008973",
      "startDate": "2022-11-13T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ]
};

const groupedReservations = initial.reservations
  .sort((reservationA, reservationB) => {
    // Sort descending according to startDate
    return new Date(reservationB.startDate) - new Date(reservationA.startDate);
  })
  .reduce((reservationGroups, reservation) =>
  {
    // Calculate the key that uniquely identifies the group, then look it up
    const date = new Date(reservation.startDate);
    const reservationMonth = monthNames[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getFullYear();
    const existingGroup = reservationGroups.find(group => group.month === reservationMonth);

    // If the group doesn't exist, create it - otherwise, add the reservation to it
    if (!existingGroup) {
      reservationGroups.push({
        itineraryId: initial.itineraryId,
        month: reservationMonth,
        reservations: [reservation]
      });
    } else {
      existingGroup.reservations.push(reservation);
    }

    return reservationGroups;
  }, []);

console.log(groupedReservations);
```

Note that I basically treat `itineraryId` as an afterthought here, since denormalizing the data didn't seem like an important step. Let me know if the context of your code requires something different.

Comment: When I added another item with a reservation in November 2022, "November 2022"  items showed us below "November 2021". Any idea what I can do to resolve the year issue?

Comment: Hmm, can't say for sure - what does the updated data look like? It's strange since the string comparison is pretty unambiguous.

Comment: @Saamer Have you tested the solution below on `November 2022` benchmark?

Comment: @Saamer I've edited my code snippet to also have a reservation for November 2022, which seems to be correctly grouped into its own November 2022 item. Is this how you're introducing the new data as well?

Comment: @Saamer Based on the problem you've illustrated in your last edit, I see what you mean. I added a basic sort (based on startDate) to the processing so the reservations (and their groups) will appear in a logical order. Let me know if you have any other questions!

Answer (score 0):

Here minified implementation

```js
// Convert ISO date to human readable date : August 2021

const formatYearMonth = (dateISO) => {
 
const formatYearMonth = (dateISO) => {

  const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
  const parsedDate =  new Date(dateISO)

  const year = parsedDate.getFullYear()
  const month = monthNames[parsedDate.getMonth()]

  return `${month} ${year}`;
};

  return `${month} ${year}`;
};

const getItineraryMonths = (reservations) => {
  let months = {};

  reservations.forEach((reservation) => {
    const formattedMonth = formatYearMonth(reservation.startDate);

    months[formattedMonth] = formattedMonth;
  });

  return Object.keys(months);
};

// Get reservation in specified month for specific itinerary

const getReservationsInMonth = (reservations, formatedMonthIn) => {
  return reservations.filter((reservation) => {
    const formattedMonth = formatYearMonth(reservation.startDate);

    return formattedMonth === formatedMonthIn;
  });
};

// Reformat JSON response

const formatJsonResponse = (response) => {
  const itineraryMonths = getItineraryMonths(response.reservations);

  const formattedResult = itineraryMonths.map((month) => {
    return {
      itineraryId: response.itineraryId,
      month,
      reservations: getReservationsInMonth(response.reservations, month),
    };
  });

  return formattedResult;
};

console.log(formatJsonResponse(input));
```

Test solution  - https://replit.com/@EmmanuelBYIRING/json-sanitise#index.js

Comment: Byiringiro I haven’t tried it yet since it requires adding another library and I m super close to getting this to work with the other solution. But I might try this

Comment: I removed date dependency library, chech updated solution